# Detecting broken linked Excel Tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, linked-tables

I am looking how to detect if a table has a broken link or not without resorting to attempting to use the table and have my access db error out. I universally have found that every resource uses code similar to this:

```
If Len(TableName.Connect) > 0 Then ...
```

or something similar but in my db if a table/file had a previously working link it maintains it's last known good .connect even if the link is broken. So checking the .connect does not work. Am I missing something? Or better yet is there a different solution to checking for broken links?

Comment: Why not let it error out? If you want to check if something is broken, testing if you can use it is a solid way. You can capture the errors, so the user won't see that any error has occurred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first, you can parse the *Connect* property:

```
FileName = Split(CurrentDb.TableDefs("LinkedExcelRange").Connect, "=")(1)
' FileName -> d:\path\yourexcelfile.xlsx
```

and check if that exists.

Comment: Parsing out the "Database=" location gives the last known full path location of the last working location, even on broken tables.

Comment: He said "and check if that exists." Lookup `FileSystemObject`  and `FileExists` method - you're still going to follow path and check for `FolderExists` if you want to avoid trapping errors

Comment: I misunderstood, Yes the FileExists method fixes this nicely. Thank you.